# GridLayout Design row column hint

Tags: java, android, sdk, grid-layout, hint

this might be a silly question but I looked everywhere and can't seem to find the right keyword to know how to solve this. Basically in my Design tab, you know when you are dragging items on a GridLayout, every tutorial I see shows that there should be like a hint where you are hovering that item like Row 1, Column 2 and also the green guide to show you the size of the GridLayout object. My Design tab doesn't have this. How do I enable it?

The row,column hint and the light green guide I'm talking about:

[image: Light Green Column Row guide]

I am using Android Studio 3.0.1.

Comment: Not sure about android studio, but I think you are talking about tooltips.

Comment: I did some more searching and found a similar (but unfortunately unanswered) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46315583/how-to-get-the-tooltip-for-element-position-while-dragging-and-dropping-in-andro